# Making the "Two-Timing" method rigorous (Perturbation theory)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, perturbation-theory

I'm reading about the method of two-timing in section 7.6 of *Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos* by Strogatz, and I have some questions about how to make this concept rigorous. In this section the book considers equations of the form
$$ \hspace{4.5cm} \ddot{x} + x + \epsilon h(x,\dot{x}) = 0  \hspace{4.5cm} (1) $$
where $0 \leq \epsilon \ll 1$, $x: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and $h: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrary smooth function. The section first covers regular perturbation theory, which I feel okay with. But then author gets to the method of two-timing for ODEs that exhibit multiple time scales, and this is where the explanation starts to feel a little hand-wavey. Here is Strogatz's description of the method:

> To apply two-timing to (1), let $\tau = t$ denote the fast $O(1)$ time, and let $T = \epsilon t$ denote the slow time. We'll treat these two times as if they were *independent* variables. In particular, functions of the slow time $T$ will be regarded as *constants* on the fast time scale $\tau$. It's hard to justify this idea rigorously, but it works. [Arg! Show me the rigor!]...Next we turn to the mechanics of the method. We expand the solution of (1) as a series
> $$ \hspace{3cm} x(t,\epsilon) = x_0(\tau, T) + \epsilon x_1(\tau, T) + O(\epsilon^2). \hspace{3cm} (2) $$
> The time derivatives in (1) are transformed according to the chain rule:
> \begin{align*}
>    \hspace{3cm} \dot{x} = \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial \tau} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial T}
>    \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial \tau} + \epsilon \frac{\partial x}{\partial T}   \hspace{3cm} (3)
> \end{align*}
> A subscript notation for differentiation is more compact; thus we write (3) as
> $$ \hspace{5.1cm} \dot{x} = \partial_{\tau} x + \epsilon \partial_T x. \hspace{5.1cm} (4) $$
>
> After substituting (2) into (4) and collecting powers of $\epsilon$, we find
> $$ \hspace{3.3cm} \dot{x} = \partial_{\tau} x_0 + \epsilon (\partial_T x_0 + \partial_{\tau} x_1) + O(\epsilon^2). \hspace{3.3cm} (5) $$
> Similarly,
> $$ \hspace{3cm} \ddot{x} = \partial_{\tau \tau} x_0 + \epsilon(\partial_{\tau \tau} x_1 + 2 \partial_{T \tau} x_0) + O(\epsilon^2). \hspace{3cm} (6) $$

**My main question**: How can we make the above ideas rigorous?

My attempt is as follows:  Given the ODE (1), we first *assume* that the solution $x(t;\epsilon)$ can be expressed as
$$ x(t;\epsilon) = X(t,\epsilon t)$$

for some function $X: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. Now let $\tau, T: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be functions defined by $\tau(t) := t$ and $T(t;\epsilon) := \epsilon t$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}, \epsilon > 0$. We then have $X(\tau(t),T(t)) = x(t;\epsilon)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}, \epsilon > 0$. The chain rule computation is then straightforward:
\begin{align*}
   \dot{X} := \frac{dX}{dt} &= \frac{\partial X}{\partial \tau} \frac{d\tau}{dt} + \frac{\partial X}{\partial T} \frac{dT}{dt} =  \frac{\partial X}{\partial \tau} + \frac{\partial X}{\partial T} \epsilon.
\end{align*}
The subsequent equations (4)-(6) should now be the same, just with $x$ replaced by $X$. (Is my interpretation correct so far?)

The Taylor expansion part is where I'm a bit perplexed: It seems that (2) is a Taylor expansion of the function $\epsilon \mapsto x(t; \epsilon)$, or equivalently, $\epsilon \mapsto X(\tau(t), T(t))$. Now if we had some arbitrary smooth function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ indexed by some parameter $\epsilon$, then I agree that the map $\epsilon \mapsto f(x,y; \epsilon)$ has some expansion
$$ f(x,y; \epsilon) = f_0(x,y) + f_1(x,y) \epsilon + f_2(x,y) \epsilon^2 + \cdots, $$

(provided that it is smooth), where the coefficient functions $f_0, f_1,\ldots$ do not depend on $\epsilon$. But my problem with (2) is that the "coefficients" of the Taylor series, namely $x_0(\tau,T), x_1(\tau,T),\ldots$ are functions of $\epsilon$, since $T$ depends on $\epsilon$. How then is this a legitimate Taylor expansion?

Also, an additional question: Is there a way to know a prior if the solution $x = x(t;\epsilon)$ to some ODE $\dot{x} = f(x)$ can be expressed in the form $x(t;\epsilon) = X(t, \epsilon t)$? Or do we generally make such an assumption based on intuition? In one of the examples that Strogatz uses, the ODE has the analytic solution $x(t) = (1-\epsilon^2)^{-1/2} e^{-\epsilon t} \cos((1-\epsilon^2)^{1/2} t)$, so clearly $X(t_1, t_2) := (1-\epsilon^2)^{-1/2} e^{-t_2} \cos((1-\epsilon^2)^{1/2} t_1)$ satisfies the requirement. But is there a way to see this a priori (i.e., if we couldn't analytically solve the ODE)?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. This two-timing concept is rather confusing to me, and I think seeing the details spelled out very rigorously would help my understanding.

Comment: I'll add to the other answers that it perturbation expansions shouldn't be thought of as Taylor series. They are a different type of series, know as an asymptotic expansion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion

Answer (score 3):

So firstly, they really should be writing $X(t, \epsilon t; \epsilon)$. Without that the expansion in terms of $x_i(\tau, T)$ doesn't quite make sense. But as you note, it *does* make sense that for any function $X(\tau, T; \epsilon)$, there exists some sequence of $x_i$ such that
$$
X(\tau, T;\epsilon) = x_0(\tau, T) + \epsilon x_1(\tau, T) + \epsilon^2x_2(\tau, T) + ...
$$

So here's what we're going to do with this. We substitute this series into the differential equation using $x(t;\epsilon) = X(t, \epsilon t;\epsilon)$, then collect orders of $\epsilon$. This will give some series of relations among the $x_i$ and their $\tau$ and $T$ derivatives when evaluated at $\tau = t$, $T = \epsilon t$. Then we add the additional requirement that the $x_i$ and their derivatives satisfy those relations for *every* $\tau, T$, which we can do because any such set of $x_i$ will of course satisfy the relations at $\tau = t, T = \epsilon t$. And now we have a set of simpler differential equations entirely in terms of $\tau$ and $T$, with no $\epsilon$s or $t$s around. If things have gone right, these can then be solved recursively order-by-order.

Answer (score 2):

Already the simple perturbation series is a deliberate decomposition of the solution that gets its justification from its result, if it works. Of course one can make a theory of and for classes of perturbation problems where it works.

In the multiple time-scale expansion, the calculator gives themselves even more freedom to distribute terms in the solution. This allows to calculate directly perturbations in the time scale that otherwise are a consequence of careful post-processing.

For instance in $\ddot x+x+ϵx^3=0$ one knows that the solutions will be closed and periodic. However the simple perturbation series will produce resonance terms that are trigonometric functions with polynomial coefficients, so the perturbation series extended to $\Bbb R$ will diverge from a closed curve. See [Help with nonlinear ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2013417/help-with-nonlinear-ode)

This can be corrected by having also a perturbation series for the frequency, see some answers in [Help with understanding Duffing's oscillator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961162/help-with-understanding-duffings-oscillator), [find an approximate solution, up to the order of epsilon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1474995/find-an-approximate-solution-up-to-the-order-of-epsilon)

However in a multi-scale expansion one can use the second (third,...) scale to set the combined coefficients of the resonance terms to zero, resulting in a systematic perturbation of the time scale. I found no direct examples for the above equation, but frequently the Mathieu equation is analyzed using multiple time scales, see [Uniform perturbative solutions to the Mathieu equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890843/uniform-perturbative-solutions-to-the-mathieu-equation), [Method of multiple scales on Mathieu's equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3497182/method-of-multiple-scales-on-mathieus-equation), or the nearly circular case of the van der Pol oscillator (incomplete treatment, detail question) [Why is $\sin^3(\tau + \phi)$ not a Secular term in the context of the van der Pol oscillator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4094687/why-is-sin3-tau-phi-not-a-secular-term-in-the-context-of-the-van-der-po?rq=1)